# Можно ли в C++ сделать так: "delete this"?

Tags: c++

Можно ли в C++ сделать так: `delete this` ?

Comment: Метод Release в COM так и реализовывается обычно

Comment: Можно, только осторожно. Вот [официальный FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) по этому поводу.

Answer (score 8):

Можно, при соблюдении ряда условий. Именно - деструктор вы сделаете `private`.

Объясню. Объект, который может самоуничтожиться, нежелательно создавать на стеке, в таком случае, деструктор может быть вызван дважды, что приведет к UB.

@Harry верно заметил, что использовать умный указатель также нежелательно. Либо, при самоуничтожении надо как-то ставить его (этот указатель) в известность о своем уходе.

@Abyx внес верное замечание о том, что скрывать надо деструктор, а не конструктор.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47694/discussion-on-answer-by-gbg----c---delete-this).

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Но после `delete this`, `this` использовать уже нельзя.